# Currently trying to migrate a module written in Swift 3 to Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods

I'm currently having some minor trouble with migrating a module written in **Swift 3** to **Swift 2.3**, while this may not be the ideal solution I'm left without options as the pod does not have another version written in **Swift 2.3**.

Another reason why I'm trying to write this module in **Swift 2.3** is because my company currently supports *legacy products* therefore, they still maintain older products for clients written in **Swift 2.3**.

With all that being said, my issue stems here:

**How would I write the following in Swift 2.3?**:

```
let rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: AnimKeys.transform)
    rotation.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity)
    rotation.duration = Constants.finishLoadingAnimDuration
    rotation.delegate = self
    assignContext(.LoadingFinishing, anim: rotation)
    for line in lines {
        rotation.fromValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: ((line.presentation() as? CAShapeLayer)?.transform)!)
        line.add(rotation, forKey: AnimKeys.lineRotation)
        finishLoadingGroup.enter()
    }
    finishLoadingGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        self.taskCompletion!(self)
    }
```

*See below for screenshot of errors on Xcode:*

[image: Errors]

Comment: What was the error when you executed this code? You should get some errors

Comment: Yeah I just added a screenshot on my original post, let me know if that is of any help. @paper1111

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main` should be something like `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`

Comment: I get _Use of unresolved identifier 'dispatch_a_sync'_ as an error when implementing the aforementioned.

Comment: `dispatch_a_sync`?!

Comment: Yup. No idea why either. Could be something wrong with the entire line. I've tried to translate it all weekend to Swift 2.3 but it seems as though it's virtually impossible without changing a lot of things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135594/discussion-between-paper1111-and-alex7).

Comment: Are you, by chance, trying to revert https://github.com/Cleveroad/CRNetworkButton to Swift 2.3 ?

Comment: No, it's: https://github.com/jagajithmk/SubmitButton @DonMag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for Swift 2.2 ... then I'd expect Xcode / you could handle any 2.2 -> 2.3 changes...

```
    // rotation for lines
    let rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
    rotation.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity)
    rotation.duration = Constants.finishLoadingAnimDuration
    rotation.delegate = self
    assignContext(.LoadingFinishing, anim: rotation)

    for line in lines {
        rotation.fromValue = NSValue(CATransform3D: (line.presentationLayer() as! CAShapeLayer).transform)
        line.addAnimation(rotation, forKey: "lineRotation")
        dispatch_group_enter( finishLoadingGroup )
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(finishLoadingGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // this may need fixing...
        self.taskCompletion!(self)
    }
```

Comment: *Tried to get it to work but there still seems to be an error at:*       dispatch_group_enter(finishLoadingGroup)
        }
        
        dispatch_group_notify(finishLoadingGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

Comment: Did you change `fileprivate let finishLoadingGroup = DispatchGroup()` to `private let finishLoadingGroup = dispatch_group_create()` ? Do you have a  repo of your conversion progress so far?